# improving performance of a view that is heavily dependent on dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

**This view is taking me HOURS to execute:**

```
USE [SalesDWH]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[FirstLastEstablished]    Script Date: 10/29/2012 15:12:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER view [dbo].[FirstLastEstablished] as


with cte_min as(

select 
      a.client_id
      ,a.specimen_source
      ,a.received_date
from
      millennium_dw_dev..F_ACCESSION_DAILY a
join
            (select distinct
                  f.client_id
                  ,f.received_date
                  ,f.accession_daily_key
            from 
                  millennium_dw_dev..F_ACCESSION_DAILY f
            join 
                  (select CLIENT_ID, MIN(received_date) MinRecDate
                  from millennium_dw_dev..F_ACCESSION_DAILY
                  group by CLIENT_ID) i
            on f.CLIENT_ID=i.CLIENT_ID
            and f.RECEIVED_DATE=i.MinRecDate) b
on    
      a.ACCESSION_DAILY_KEY=b.ACCESSION_DAILY_KEY 

)

,
cte_max as 
(

select 
      a.client_id
      ,a.specimen_source
      ,a.received_date
from
      millennium_dw_dev..F_ACCESSION_DAILY a
join
            (select distinct
                  f.client_id
                  ,f.received_date
                  ,f.accession_daily_key
            from 
                  millennium_dw_dev..F_ACCESSION_DAILY f
            join 
                  (select CLIENT_ID, max(received_date) MaxRecDate
                  from millennium_dw_dev..F_ACCESSION_DAILY
                  group by CLIENT_ID) i
            on f.CLIENT_ID=i.CLIENT_ID
            and f.RECEIVED_DATE=i.MaxRecDate) b
on    
      a.ACCESSION_DAILY_KEY=b.ACCESSION_DAILY_KEY 

)
,


cte_est as

(

select distinct client_id, MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED
from millennium_dw_dev..D_CLIENT
where REC_ACTIVE_FLG=1
and MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED is not null
)

,

mainQuery as(
select distinct
      f.client_id
      ,cmin.specimen_source first_specimen_source
      ,cmin.received_date first_received
      ,cmax.specimen_source last_specimen_source
      ,cmax.received_date last_received
      ,cest.MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED
from millennium_dw_dev..F_ACCESSION_DAILY f
left join cte_max cmax
on cmax.CLIENT_ID=f.CLIENT_ID
left join cte_min cmin
on cmin.CLIENT_ID=f.CLIENT_ID
left join cte_est cest
on cest.CLIENT_ID=f.CLIENT_ID
)
,
DateDifferences
as

(
SELECT
client_id,
   (DATEDIFF(dd, MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED,first_received) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED,first_received) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, first_received) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 -(case when cast('01/01/2008 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('05/26/2008 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('07/04/2008 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('09/01/2008 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('11/27/2008 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('12/25/2008 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('01/01/2009 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('05/25/2009 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('07/03/2009 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('09/07/2009 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('11/26/2009 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('12/25/2009 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('01/01/2010 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('05/31/2010 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('07/05/2010 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('09/06/2010 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('11/25/2010 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('12/24/2010 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('01/03/2011 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('05/30/2011 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('07/04/2011 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('09/05/2011 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('11/24/2011 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('12/26/2011 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('01/02/2012 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('05/28/2012 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('07/04/2012 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('09/03/2012 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('11/22/2012 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)
-(case when cast('12/25/2012 ' as date) between MLIS_DATE_ESTABLISHED and first_received then 1 else 0 end)


   DifferenceExcludingWeekends
  from
  mainQuery
)
,
Territory 
as
(
select distinct c.client_id,c.MLIS_TERRITORY,s.REGION_NAME
from millennium_dw_dev..D_CLIENT c
left join millennium_dw_dev..D_SALES_HIERARCHY s
on s.TERRITORY_NAME=c.MLIS_TERRITORY
where c.REC_ACTIVE_FLG=1
and s.REC_ACTIVE_FLG=1

)

select mainQuery.*,d.DifferenceExcludingWeekends,Territory.MLIS_TERRITORY,Territory.REGION_NAME
from mainQuery
left join DateDifferences d
on mainQuery.CLIENT_ID=d.CLIENT_ID
left join Territory
on mainQuery.CLIENT_ID=Territory.CLIENT_ID

GO
```

I did the sql server database tuning on this, and created all the recommended indexes. After 15min of executing the view again, I stopped it.

**Are there obvious things that you could kindly point out to me about my query to optimize it more and improve execution time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are utilizing the "Common" aspect of a CTE. Try putting table: millennium_dw_dev..F_ACCESSION_DAILY in a CTE first (Only the necessary fields and records if possible). Your code selects from this table 8 times (and is this table local?).

Several of your other CTE's are referenced once, but I can see how one builds on the other. Yes they can help to break-down a complex query into more managable parts, but it may not help with performance.

Performance may not be an issue here, but getting those hard-coded dates into some sort of Holiday/Day-Off table would help as well. Having a [date table](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26565/Generate-Date-Table-in-SQL-Server) may be a better route than all these calculations.

Depending on the size of data, putting this into a stored procedure would allow the use of indexed temp tables.

Comment: thank you very much! i did not know selecting only a subset of fields from a table would effect performance! im going to try and let you know

Comment: unfortunately not so much luck wiht this one! query has been running 15min so far

Comment: jef, i actually dont know how to put the CTE's together (thats what i used them :)